# Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.ts(2511)

Tags: typescript, class, abstract-class, typescript-generics

I have the following abstract class:

```ts
abstract class A<T> {
    constructor(public a: T) { }

    get clone(): A<T> {
        return new A<T>(this.a);
    }
}
```

which gives the error

```
Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.ts(2511)
```

If I would make `clone` abstract

```ts
abstract get clone(): A<T>;
```

and declare it on my class extension like so

```ts
class B extends A<string> {
    get clone(): B {
        return new B(this.a);
    }
}
```

I would solve the error and get the expected behaviour. **But all my class extensions should have a `clone` like this.** So, how can I define `clone` generically, inside my abstract class?

Comment: You could do `new this.constructor(this.a)` but that is **unsafe** because child classes may not have the correct construct signature...

Comment: I get it running using `return new (this.constructor as new (a: T) => this)(this.a)`, which does not feel perfectly safe; but do I not already have declared a construct signature for all class extension of `A` to be `(a: T)` anyway? Why is `as new (...)` necessary?

Comment: Ok, I guess it is because `B` could override constructor of `A` and implement a different signature...